# how to make a photon weapon?

Tags: weapons, hard-science, light

How would one go about making a photon weapon? I've thought about this for a bit, but with my very limited knowledge of light and waves/particles/sciency stuff I have come up with the following:

- We're already bombarded by photons every day(sun, light bulbs, etc), so to do any damage you'd need a lot of photons.
- photons are small, so you need a lot in a concentrated area.
- you need something to make all these photons, which would probably

  - get really hot
  - need a big power source
  - and be really bright

which leads me to the questions of:

- would the effects be negated by sunscreen?
- since light is particle/wave, which would be more deadly, and how to keep it as a light or wave?
- how would someone create the needed photons?

I know next to nothing about light, and the wikipedia page makes 0 sense to me.

Comment: Eurovision is a very potent photon-based weapon...with a soundtrack.

Comment: Downvoted for appalling lack of background knowledge. Go read/watch some sci-fi; photonic weapons (most often "lasers") are *everywhere* in fiction and, as Mary noted, we've even played with them in real life. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed-energy_weapon) might be a good place to start.

Comment: *"the wikipedia page makes 0 sense to me."* Unfortunately for you we usually go into deeper details than Wikipedia, specially when we see a [tag:hard-science] tag.

Comment: [Laser canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_weapon) are being actively developed in multiple countries; for example, the United States has the [ZEUS HLONS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZEUS-HLONS_(HMMWV_Laser_Ordnance_Neutralization_System)) solid-state laser weapon and the [AN/SEQ-3 Laser Weapon System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/SEQ-3_Laser_Weapon_System) in commission and active use.

Comment: "the wikipedia page makes 0 sense to me." That's why we end up watching youtube science videos instead! lol.

Answer (score 4):

**laser**

This shoots out photons in a very coherent manner, thus enabling them to hit their target with maximum effect.  With sufficient power, they can be very dangerous.

And, it already exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, given the OP's stated knowledge, he probably doesn't even know what it means for photons to be coherent or incoherent. Also, a correction to your post: although lasers always produce a coherent beam, they do not always produce a collimated, parallel beam. They are different things. Coherence allows you to use lenses to produce a collimated, parallel beam which then lets you hit things at a distance. Diode lasers, for example will produce a coherent, but uncollimated beam with significant divergence. Lenses are then required to collimate the beam.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic radiation is made of photons.  All of it.

[image: emr]

[http://www.columbia.edu/~vjd1/electromag_spectrum.htm](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Evjd1/electromag_spectrum.htm)

The difference between kinds of light is the difference between the wavelength of the photon.  Very long wavelength is radio waves, but there are photons with even longer wavelengths than that - [ultra low frequency radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_low_frequency) with wavelengths of many kilometers.  There are microwaves a little higher frequency than radio.  Visible light is higher frequency than that, then come X-rays and gamma rays at the highest frequency and shortest wavelength.

It is all light.  If you want to make a weapon, you know how these different kinds of electromagnetic radiation could work.  Microwaves can heat water.  Visible light can burn things.  X-rays and gamma rays are "ionizing radiation" can disrupt molecules with their energy.

Photon weapons are as common as aliens in SF.  Lasers, blasters, glowy death rays, radiation; yes yes.  Things get burnt, or blow up, or get burnt then blow up.  The challenge is to make it interesting.  I propose a beam weapon using ultra low sub radio frequency photons intended to mess with the minds of the target and make them hallucinate and see ghosts.  Except it turns out they are not hallucinations...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so photons. Lets just go with a particle model for now (the whole particle/wave thing really depends on what model you're using and it turns out that the most accurate model boils down to "light is a bunch of math").

So lets consider two things about these photons: the number of photons, and how much energy each photon carries. You can have a ton of photons, but if they're all low-energy it won't do a ton. We get lots of low-energy photons bouncing around us all the time; that's what visible light is. If you up the energy though, things get fun, at least for health physicists. Basically once you hit 100 keV/photon you've got gamma radiation, and you can just keep cranking up the energy from there. One relatively easy way to get gammas is just muck about with heavy elements; their decay chains usually kick off some pretty nice radiation.

Effects of gamma radiation: ok, so there are basically 3 categories of radiation damage, but you probably don't really care about the effects on following generations, so let's focus of somatic effects: long-term you've got cancer, basically. Some other stuff too, like cataracts, but cancer's the biggie. Short term, depends on how much you get hit with, but you can end up with anything from "mild sunburn equivalent" to "total organ failure".

TLDR: if you crank the energy of the photons up they do a lot more damage and you don't need nearly so many. Gamma radiation is not healthy.

Comment: Gamma really isn't the best wave. It is dangerous as it goes through a lot of things before hitting something. That means we can't shield ourselves well. But if it goes through things, it also goes through people, wasting energy. Depending on what you want to do, you probably want a beam with as high energy value as possible that isn't penetrating too much.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just going with gamma because the question specified photons, and gammas are the most dangerous photons I've worked with